# load an adobe dynamic form file

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, livecycle-designer

I have a .pdf created through Adobe LiveCycle Designer (it's a dynamic pdf ) i want to add this pdf to my windows app

this is what i tried

```
File file1 = new File(fileName);
System.Xml.XmlDocument xfadoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xfadoc.LoadXml(fileName);
```

here's how i get filename

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
dialog.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf) | *.pdf | All Files (*.*) | *.* | xdp files (*.xdp) | *.xdp ";
dialog.FilterIndex = 2;
dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
dialog.CheckFileExists = true;
dialog.DefaultExt = "pdf | xdp";
fileName = dialog.FileName.ToString();
```

but when i click on open file button and browse to where i have stored it ; it doesnot even appear

Also when i try to load this file in my C# windows app it gives me an exception at the following line

```
 xfadoc.LoadXml(fileName);
```

the exception says that

```
'Data at root level is invalid'
```

If i say that i have loaded the string (filepath name) someone please tell me how can i extract the xml part only form this dynamic file

Comment: Traditionally, it's been better to tell us _which_ exception you received. You should include the results of `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Filter` without spaces in extensions part.

```
dialog.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*|xdp files (*.xdp)|*.xdp";
```

Answer (score 0):

[LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) loads the document from the string parameter. You want to use the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx) method.